# Why does Enzyme's `find()` incorrectly return elements that don't exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Below I have an example React component that behaves as follows -

- When the `showDiv` state is `false` (initial state), it renders nothing.
- When the `showDiv` state is updated to `true` (maybe by some external component, redux, etc..), it renders a `<div>` with a single radio input.

I've also included Jest tests:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showDiv: false };
  }

  render() {
    const { showDiv } = this.state;

    if (!showDiv) { return null; }

    return (
      <div className='my-component'>
        <input type="radio" value="yes" id="foo" checked={true} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
  });

  it('should render the div', () => {
    // This INCORRECTLY passes
    expect(wrapper.find('#foo').at(0)).to.not.be.null;
    expect(wrapper.find('#foo').at(0)).to.be.checked;
  });
});
```

I wrote the test to verify that the `<input>` exists and that it is `checked`, and the test passes.

However, on initial component mount/load that `<input>` should not be rendered (since `showDiv` is `false`), so why is the test passing?

I even output the state of the component with `console.log(wrapper.find('#foo').at(0).debug());` and I can verify that nothing is being rendered... but it still passes.

```
$ npx jest --no-cache --config test/js/jest.config.js test/js/components/test.spec.jsx

  ● Console

    console.log test/js/components/test.spec.jsx:34
```

Any reason why this gives a false positive? Specifically, why the `find()` returns elements that don't exist, but still pass the checks (e.g. `.to.be.checked`)

Comment: Could there be an indexing problem and/or a low-level memory management problem?  I am not familiar with "Enzyme" this is just 'general speculation' ...